# Creating composite Javascript/HTML "widgets"

Tags: javascript, html, widget

What I would like to do is be able to dynamically a block of self-contained HTML that has additional properties.

I'm not sure what to call it, as "widget" now implies it is something like flair or a badge to put on your blog. I am talking about a reusable, customizable, "composite" JS/HTML(/CSS) object.

For example, a simple date picker.

```
document.body.appendChild(new DatePicker());
```

Would generate

```
<div class="datepicker" name="...">
    <select class="datepicker_monthSelect">
        <option value="0">January</option>
        ....
    </select>
    <select class="datepicker_daySelect">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        ....
    </select>
    <select class="datepicker_yearSelect">
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        ....
    </select>
</div>
```

And would have properties like

```
var d = new DatePicker();
d.value = "2010-06-21";
d.name = "the_datepicker";
d.month = 5;
d.month = "June";
d.day = 21;
d.year = 2010;
```

How can this be (easily) accomplished? What are the best practices for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the MooTools approach of doing this. Any JavaScript object can define a `toElement` method and you can append this object to the DOM using MooTools' wrappers. The wrappers will query the `toElement` property on the object, and if it exists, then the return value of calling `toElement()` will be appended to the DOM. For this to work, you would have to use the wrappers for appending to DOM instead of using `appendChild` directly.

```
function DatePicker(date) {
    this.date = date;
}

DatePicker.prototype.toElement = function() {
    // return a DOM representation of this object
};

var picker = new DatePicker();
```

Here are some ways to go about using this:

```
// retrieve the DOM node directly
document.body.appendChild(picker.toElement());

// use a wrapper to append, that queries toElement first
// DOM is a function like jQuery, that wraps the given DOM
// object with additional methods like append for querying toElement.
DOM(document.body).append(picker);
```

Of course, you can always overwrite the native `appendChild` method, however, I would **not** recommend this.

For the sake of completeness, this is how you would do it though. Use a closure to hold on to the original `appendChild` method, and replace it with a new method that first checks if `toElement` is defined, and retrieves the element representation of that object if it does. Otherwise, proceed with adding the passed-in object as it is.

```
(function(original) {
    Element.prototype.appendChild = function(child) {
        if('toElement' in child) {
            original.call(this, child.toElement());
        }
        else {
            original.call(this, child);
        }
    }
})(Element.prototype.appendChild);
```

Add the object to DOM as in your example:

```
document.body.appendChild(new DatePicker());
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different options with this.

You could 'subclass' the element object but that would be extremely inefficient as Javascript pretend to be as little Object-Oriented as possible. (Plus, extending host objects is [yuck](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).)

However, the approach that I would take would be to define a `to_html` function on the `DatePicker` 'class'.

This method would theoretically take the attributes of the `DatePicker` and use them to create the HTML.

And, if you keep this HTML stored in the `DatePicker`, you would have an easy way to update it and access its value as needed further in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to check out knockout.composite - http://danderson00.blogspot.com.au/2012/08/introducing-knockoutcomposite.html